# Does every integer $n > 2$ have an arithmetic expression involving at least two consecutive integers but excluding $n$ itself?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example:

$10 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4$

$11 = 1 - 2 + 3 \times 4$

$12 = 3 \times 4$

$13 = -(1 - 2) + 3 \times 4$

$14 = 2 + 3 + 4 + 5$

$15 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5$

$16 = (2/3)(4/5)(6 + 7 + 8 + 9)$

$17 = 1 + (2/3)(4/5)(6 + 7 + 8 + 9)$

$18 = (1 + 2)3!$

$19 = 4! - 5$

Obviously any triangular number has such an expression, as well as numbers one less than a triangular number. But how to prove it for other numbers? Or is there a counterexample?

Comment: $n=(n+1)+(n+2)-(n+3)$ ?

Comment: So painfully simple...!+1

Comment: I presume the OP means consecutive positive integers strictly smaller than $n$. A fact that you can use: Every number that is not a power of $2$ is a sum of consecutive positive integers (all smaller than itself). For instance, $11 = 5 + 6$, $12 = 3 + 4 + 5$, $13 = 6 + 7$, $17 = 8 + 9$, $18 = 5 + 6 + 7$, $19 = 9 + 10$, etc. (For proof, see [here](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Pong-1-0750774.pdf) or [here](http://mathblag.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/sums-of-consecutive-integers/).) So it's enough to ask the (suitably modified) question for powers of $2$.

Comment: Why do you presume such a thing, @ShreevatsaR ? Some of the examples of the OP don't even use integers...or even positive integers.

Comment: $(2-1)+(2-1)+(2-1)...$ $n$ times

Comment: @DonAntonio: The title of the question mentions "integers". I interpret the examples as always using some set of consecutive positive integers in order (and in particular each integer exactly once), but the set of allowed operations includes negation/subtraction and division.

Comment: Exactly @ShreevatsaR, and thus the comment by user127.0.0.1 solves the question...Also, both examples 16-17 use fractional numbers, say...

Comment: Technically the best answer is the first comment. But the more interesting answer is Shreevatsa's.

Comment: If $n$ is odd then $n = (\frac{n-1}{2})+(\frac{n+1}{2})$. If $n$ is even then $n = 1+(\frac{n}{2}-1)+(\frac{n}{2})$.

Comment: @DonAntonio There is no such thing as a fractional integer, so the OP's examples for 16 and 17 must be interpreted as using the consecutive integers $2,3,4,\dots $ (with division), rather than as using arbitrary fractions like $2/3$. As for whether the consecutive integers must all be less than $n$ (as in all the examples) or not, we can await the OP's clarification, though there doesn't seem to be much doubt about which one is the less trivial question. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, why do you inform me there is no such thing as "fractional integers"? Did you even read what I wrote?

Comment: I do consider it okay for there to include integers greater than $n$. Just so long as not $n$ itself. Therefore User127's comment is the best answer but not the most interesting.

Comment: I think the consecutive numbers version of this question is interesting enough that it deserves its own question.  In the meantime, if @user127.0.0.1's answer is acceptable, please post it as an answer so that it can be accepted and this form of the question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: done :)

Comment: @DonAntonio: I didn't mean to annoy you — yes I did read what you wrote, but I could ask you the same question. :-) To clarify: this discussion started when you said that "Some of the examples of the OP don't even use integers", and I pointed out that all the OP's examples could indeed be seen as using integers, true to the question title. Then again you said that the OP's examples for 16 and 17 use fractional numbers (rather than integers?), and I pointed out that that cannot be the way to interpret it, because the OP specifically mentions integers. Is something not clear?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, behold example 16: $\;\frac23\cdot\ldots\;$ . What do you call that number $\;\frac23\;$ there? An integer?

Comment: @DonAntonio When you divide two integers, you can get a fractional number. But you cannot use that fact to conclude that the example doesn't use integers. For example, in $10 = 1+2+3+4$, we have $3+4=7$, but it would be absurd to say that because the example "uses" $7$ which is not consecutive with $1$ and $2$, the example does not satisfy the constraints of the question. :-)

Comment: @DonAntonio: Actually this discussion has been useful to me, thanks. Let me declare a bias I just realized: I prefer to interpret the examples in such a way that they fit the question. (It is possible to interpret them differently; that is your prerogative.) As the question is not specified unambiguously, nor is it specified how the examples map to the question (e.g. it doesn't say "in the example $10=1+2+3+4$, the consecutive integers used are $1,2,3,4$), there is some leeway in interpretation. E.g. you could say in $11=1-2+3\times4$ that the integers used are $1,-2,3,4$, not consecutive. (…)

Comment: @DonAntonio: (…) I'd not prefer this interpretation as it invalidates the question; I'd prefer to interpret that it's the integers $1,2,3,4$ that are used. Similarly, there is also some leeway in interpreting the question based on the examples (the problem of induction). I chose to interpret the tightest question that fits the examples (and also match the remark at the end on triangular numbers), but yes you could interpret it differently: e.g. $16=(2/3)(4/5)(6+7+8+9)$, which uses consecutive integers $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ can be interpreted as using fractions, and thus not fit the question. :-)

Comment: @DonAntonio: Similarly, $19=4!-5$ can be interpreted as using the integers $24$ and $5$, instead of two consecutive integers $4$ and $5$. Such interpretations seem perverse to me, but now I realize that's only because of my bias of trying to have the question make sense. (One can even literally interpret the wording in the title as saying that we just have to use at least two consecutive integers and then can use anything else at all—say $n=(n-3)+1+2$ where $1,2$ are consecutive—but I tend not to gravitate towards such "finding loopholes".) But I agree one's personal choice may be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every integer $n$ can be written as
$$n= (n+1)+(n+2)-(n+3)$$
where $(n+1)$ and $(n+2)$ are of course two consecutive integers.

Comment: Rather, $(n+1)$, $(n+2)$ and $(n+3)$ are three consecutive integers. +1.